# How can I fill data in table from two other tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert

**table1**

```
id    name
1     aaa
2     bbb
3     ccc
```

and

**table2**

```
id  lastname   address
1   bbbb       asd
2   aaaa       asda
3   aaaa       asdsd
4   aaaa       asdsfd
```

to

**table3**

```
id    Fname     lName      address
1     aaa       bbbb       asd
2     bbb       aaaa       asda
3     ccc       aaaa       asdsd
```

Is it possible to do using SQL query and stored procedure?

Comment: ya just join using id

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.name fname,
       b.lastname lname,
       b.address
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
```

You can also create `table3` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT a.name fname,
       b.lastname lname,
       b.address
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
```

This works in almost all known database engines, except for  MSSQL ([**SQLFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6c613/1)). In MSSQL, use `SELECT ... INTO ...` instead:

```
SELECT a.name fname,
       b.lastname lname,
       b.address
INTO table3
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: answer updated with solution for all db engines supported by SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things:

1. make a select statement
2. make an stored procedure
3. make a view

what kind of database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cross Join. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

```
Select * into tableWhatever from A
CROSS JOIN B
```

You should research a little bit more before posting.

Comment: From what it seems, he is combining the 2 tables into one and thats what cross join does.